# Find and replace values in Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, replace, find

Is it possible to find and replace all values in a database that contain certain character.

Table is around 50 rows and 50 columns and since all values, except those in first column (actually, second, since first are IDs) are "X" or DBnulls and are spread randomly.

After I open a connection with a database I should use loop to find values that meet two criteria : length of 1 char and value of "X" and replace them with DBNulls.

Can some1 please help me the loop part, 'cause I don't know where to begin.

```
  Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\PD_ZN.mdb"
        Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM ZAKUPN"
        Dim OleDBConn1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()
        Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, OleDBConn1)
        OleDBConn1.Open()
```

Comment: i think you can do with sql query, access has `replace` function, for condition u can use `switch`. in access you cant use `case`

Comment: **Database is around 50 rows and 50 columns**?? Do you mean table?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an `IIF` function for this scenario.

Try this:

```
IIf((Len([YourTbl].[Field1])=1) And ([YourTbl].[Field1]="X"),NULL,[YourTbl].[Field1])
```

We check the length of the string (it can't be more than 1 character), and if it is simply the character "X" - you can change it to `NULL`.

[Len Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/len.php)

[IIF Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx)